# Solving a logic riddle in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm in the "early phase" of learning prolog and came across a logic riddle that seams easy to implement:

[Link to the riddle](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.logisch-gedacht.de%2Flogikraetsel%2F10stellige-zahl%2F) | [Link to solution](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.logisch-gedacht.de%2Flogikraetsel%2F10stellige-zahl%2Floesung%2F&sandbox=1)

---

We are looking for the 10-digit number which satisfies the following conditions:

- All digits from 0-9 occur exactly once.
- The first 2 digits are divisible by 2.
- The first 3 digits are divisible by 3.

...

- The first 10 digits are divisible by 10.

---

I think I would first need to implement the rules to the .pl file right?
The rules from the solution are:

- An integer can be divided by 1 without remainder.
- An integer is divisible by 2 without remainder, if the last digit is straight.
- An integer can be divided by 3 without a remainder if its transverse sum is divisible by 3.
- An integer can be divided by 4 without a remainder if the last two digits are divisible by 4.
- An integer is divisible by 5 if the last digit is divisible by 5.
- An integer is divisible by 6 without a remainder if its transverse sum is divisible by 3 and the last digit by 2.
- An integer is divisible by 8 without a remainder if the last three digits are divisible by 8.
- An integer is divisible by 9 without a remainder if its transverse sum is divisible by 9.
- An integer is divisible by 10 without a remainder if the last digit is a 0.

---

I read multiple introductions to rules in prolog but still dont get how do it. Can anyone help? Would be great :)

Comment: Perhaps this logic riddle isn't as easy to implement as you originally expected. I wouldn't get too bound up in the tabular solution you linked. The Prolog solution may not mirror it. If you're just learning, perhaps choose some simpler problems to get started.

Comment: 7 is missing! .. if its weighted alternating traverse sum is divisible by 7 - weighted with 1 3 2 -1 -3 -2 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach to solving this kind of problem in Prolog is to generate all possibilities, and then filter them. In this case we need a list of the ten digits with no repetitions, and each prefix of length N should be evenly divisible by N.

```
puzzle([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J]) :-
  select(A,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],List1),
  select(B,List1,List2), select(C,List2,List3), select(D,List3,List4),
  select(E,List4,List5), select(F,List5,List6), select(G,List6,List7),
  select(H,List7,List8), select(I,List8,List9), List9 = [J],
  divisible([A,B],2),
  divisible([A,B,C],3),
  divisible([A,B,C,D],4),
  divisible([A,B,C,D,E],5),
  divisible([A,B,C,D,E,F],6),
  divisible([A,B,C,D,E,F,G],7),
  divisible([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H],8),
  divisible([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],9),
  divisible([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J],10).
```

Even divisibility can be easily implemented:

```
divisible(Is,D) :-
  combine(Is,N),
  R is N rem D, R == 0.
```

But then we also need a bunch of technicalities to convert between integers, characters, and atoms.

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

combine(Is,N) :-
  maplist(conv,Is,As), concat_list(As,A),
  atom_chars(A,Cs), number_chars(N,Cs).

conv(I,A) :-
  number_chars(I,[C]), atom_chars(A,[C]).

concat_list([A1,A2|As],Atom) :-
  atom_concat(A1,A2,A3),
  concat_list([A3|As],Atom).
concat_list([A],A).
```

This produces the result indicated in your link:

```
| ?- puzzle(X).
X = [3,8,1,6,5,4,7,2,9,0] ? ;
no
| ?-
```

Addition: if you want to make it faster, rather than just buying a bigger computer like everybody else, you can interleave the generation & test parts of the code:

```
puzzle2([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J]) :-
  select(A,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],List1),
  select(B,List1,List2), divisible([A,B],2),
  select(C,List2,List3), divisible([A,B,C],3),
  select(D,List3,List4), divisible([A,B,C,D],4),
  select(E,List4,List5), divisible([A,B,C,D,E],5),
  select(F,List5,List6), divisible([A,B,C,D,E,F],6),
  select(G,List6,List7), divisible([A,B,C,D,E,F,G],7),
  select(H,List7,List8), divisible([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H],8),
  select(I,List8,List9), divisible([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],9),
  List9 = [J], divisible([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J],10).
```

Using SWI Prolog, I get the following timings:

```
?- time((puzzle(_),false)).
32m% 142,709,118 inferences, 76.333 CPU in 76.650 seconds (100% CPU, 1869553 Lips)

?- time((puzzle2(_),false)).
32m% 157,172 inferences, 0.142 CPU in 0.144 seconds (98% CPU, 1108945 Lips)

?- time((num(_),false)).
32m% 2,802,204 inferences, 1.008 CPU in 1.028 seconds (98% CPU, 2779208 Lips)
```

which would seem to suggest that the `puzzle2` version is several times faster than the `num` version given below.

Comment: `R is N rem D, R == 0.` you sure mean `0 =:= N mod D`.

Comment: The only difference between `rem` and `mod` is the sign, which is not important when we are comparing against zero.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me and I understood what you were doing.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have tagged this with [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), I would like to augment the existing answer with additional information about **constraints**.

Importantly, constraints let you often *avoid* the generation of all combinations by **pruning** the search space for you.

We can start by *relating* a list of *digits* to the *integer* described by these digits:

```
digits_integer(Ds0, I) :-
        reverse(Ds0, Ds),
        Ds0 ins 0..9,
        foldl(pow, Ds, 0-0, I-_).

pow(D, I0-P0, I-P) :-
        I #= I0 + D*10^P0,
        P #= P0 + 1.
```

Here are two example queries:

```
?- digits_integer([1,2,3], I).
I = 123.

?- digits_integer(Ds, 302).
Ds = [3, 0, 2] .
```

Next, let us describe that a prefix of length `N` of the list `Ls` is *divisible* by `N`:

```
n_divisible(Ls, N) :-
        length(Prefix, N),
        append(Prefix, _, Ls),
        digits_integer(Prefix, I),
        I mod N #= 0.
```

The whole solution can thus be described as:

```
solution(Ds) :-
        length(Ds, 10),
        Ds ins 0..9,
        all_distinct(Ds),
        E in 2..10,
        findall(E, indomain(E), Es),
        maplist(n_divisible(Ds), Es).
```

Sample query:

```
?- solution(Ds), label(Ds).
Ds = [3, 8, 1, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0] ;
false.
```

Let us briefly compare the *performance* of the two solutions:

```
?- time((puzzle(Vs),false)).
% 142,709,119 inferences, 14.865 CPU in 14.867 seconds
```

vs.:

```
?- time((solution(Ds),label(Ds),false)).
% 19,384,173 inferences, 2.166 CPU in 2.166 seconds
```

Thus, the constraint-based approach is **several times faster** in this concrete case. This is mostly due to the power of constraint **propagation**, which the solver performs *automatically*.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different approach with CLP(FD). First let's consider a predicate, that describes a relation between a list, its first n elements and the number those n elements yield. This version is somewhat similar but less general than @mat's `digits_integer/2`.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

digits_firstn_number_(_D,0,Num,Num).
digits_firstn_number_([D|Ds],X1,Num,Acc0) :-
   X1 #> 0,
   X0 #= X1-1,
   Acc1 #= Acc0*10+D,
   digits_firstn_number_(Ds,X0,Num,Acc1).
```

The calling predicate `num/1` consists of a goal `num_/2`, that describes the actual relation and a second goal `label/1` that is labeling the list of digits which is the second argument of `num_/2`. As a minor difference to @mat's version `num/1` has the actual number rather than the list of digits as an argument:

```
num(Num) :-
   num_(Num,Digits),     % <- actual relation
   label(Digits).        % <- labeling the digits
```

The actual relation, `num_/2` differs insofar, as the divisibility rules are, wherever possible, expressed as constraints on the respective digits (as suggested in the solution you linked) rather than on the corresponding numbers:

```
num_(Num,Digits) :-
   Digits=[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J],
   Digits ins 0..9,
   all_distinct(Digits),                     % divisibility for:
   0 #= B mod 2,                             % <- first 2 digits
   0 #= (A+B+C) mod 3,                       % <- first 3 digits
   digits_firstn_number_([C,D],2,Num4,0),    % <- first 4 digits
   0 #= Num4 mod 4,                          % <- first 4 digits
   0 #= (E) mod 5,                           % <- first 5 digits
   0 #= (A+B+C+D+E+F) mod 3,                 % <- first 6 digits
   0 #= F mod 2,                             % <- first 6 digits
   digits_firstn_number_(Digits,7,Num7,0),   % <- first 7 digits
   0 #= Num7 mod 7,                          % <- first 7 digits
   digits_firstn_number_([F,G,H],3,Num8,0),  % <- first 8 digits
   0 #= Num8 mod 8,                          % <- first 8 digits
   0 #= (A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I) mod 9,           % <- first 9 digits
   J #= 0,                                   % <- all 10 digits
   digits_firstn_number_(Digits,10,Num,0).   % <- the actual number
```

The downside of this approach (besides more code) is, that it is exceedingly tailored towards this specific puzzle while @mat's version can be more easily extended to search for numbers with a different amount of digits with similar constraints (first n digits divisible by n). On the upside this approach is faster (compared with SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 6.6.4)):

```
?- time((num(Num),false)).
% 2,544,064 inferences, 0.486 CPU in 0.486 seconds (100% CPU, 5235403 Lips)
false.

?- time((solution(Ds),label(Ds),false)).
% 19,289,281 inferences, 3.323 CPU in 3.324 seconds (100% CPU, 5805472 Lips)
false.
```

And of course, `num/1` yields the same solution:

```
?- num(Num).
Num = 3816547290 ;
false.
```